# WCF Data Services + JSON throws Exception when adding entity with m:n relations

Tags: json, wcf-data-services

I run into a serious problem after changing from Atom to JSON (Light).
We use WCF Data Services 5.6 and configured it to use json in order to reduce the amount of data over the wire...

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"de-AT","value":"An error occurred while     processing this request."},
"innererror":{"message":"Multiple annotations with the name 'odata.bind' were detected for the property with name 'Employees'. In OData, duplicate annotations are not allowed.","type":"Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException","stacktrace":"  
 at Microsoft.Data.OData.DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker.AddODataPropertyAnnotation(String propertyName, String annotationName, Object annotationValue)\r\n   
 at Microsoft.Data.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightDeserializer.ProcessPropertyAnnotation(String annotatedPropertyName, String annotationName, DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, Func`2 readPropertyAnnotationValue)\r\n   
 at Microsoft.Data.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightDeserializer.ParseProperty(DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, Func`2 readPropertyAnnotationValue, String& parsedPropertyName)\r\n   
at Microsoft.Data.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightDeserializer.ProcessProperty(DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, Func`2 readPropertyAnnotationValue, Action`2 handleProperty)\r\n   
 at Microsoft.Data.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightEntryAndFeedDeserializer.ReadEntryContent(IODataJsonLightReaderEntryState entryState)\r\n   
 at Microsoft.Data.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadAtNavigationLinkEndImplementationSynchronously()\r\n   
 at Microsoft.Data.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadAtNavigationLinkEndImplementation()\r\n   
at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadImplementation()\r\n   
 at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadSynchronously()\r\n   
 at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.InterceptException[T](Func`1 action)\r\n   
 at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.Read()\r\n  
 at System.Data.Services.Serializers.EntityDeserializer.ReadEntry(ODataReader odataReader, SegmentInfo topLevelSegmentInfo)\r\n  
 at System.Data.Services.Serializers.EntityDeserializer.Read(SegmentInfo segmentInfo)\r\n  
 at System.Data.Services.Serializers.ODataMessageReaderDeserializer.Deserialize(SegmentInfo segmentInfo)"}}}
```

Our client side code looks like the following snippet:

**ViewModel**

```
//Insert control
var control = new Control
{
     Name = this.Name,
     ShortName = this.ShortName,
     ////etc...
};

this.ControlAgent.AddToContext(control);

foreach (var emp in this.EnforcingEmpColl.AddedItems)
{
     this.ControlAgent.AddEnforcingEmployee(control, emp);
}

this.ControlAgent.SaveControl(control, (s1, e1) => { ////etc.. });
```

**ControlAgent**

```
public class ControlServiceAgent : ServiceAgentBase<Control>, IControlServiceAgent
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ControlServiceAgent"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public ControlServiceAgent()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ControlServiceAgent"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">service uri</param>
    public ControlServiceAgent(Uri uri)
        : base(uri)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an Enforcing Emp to the Control
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="control">control</param>
    /// <param name="emp">enforcing Employee</param>
    public void AddEnforcingEmployee(Control control, Employee emp)
    {
        this.Context.AttachTo("Employees", emp, "*");
        this.Context.AddLink(control, "Employees", emp);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an control to the context
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">entity to add</param>
    public void AddToContext(Control entity)
    {
        this.Context.AddToControls(entity);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds and saves a control and notifies the tree
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">control to add</param>
    /// <param name="handler">callback</param>
    public void SaveControl(Control entity, EventHandler<ResponseEventArgs<Control>> handler)
    {   
        this.Context.BeginSaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate, 
            ar =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        DataServiceResponse response = this.Context.EndSaveChanges(ar);
                        Control controlToAdd = null;

                        // Enumerate the returned responses.
                        foreach (ChangeOperationResponse change in response)
                        {
                            // Get the descriptor for the entity.
                            var descriptor = change.Descriptor as EntityDescriptor;

                            if (descriptor != null)
                            {
                                controlToAdd = descriptor.Entity as Control;
                            }
                        }

                        if (controlToAdd == null)
                        {
                            handler(this, new ResponseEventArgs<Control>("[SP-Control]: Error while SaveControl. Saving the added control failed!", null));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            handler(this, new ResponseEventArgs<Control>(controlToAdd));
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        handler(this, new ResponseEventArgs<Control>("[SP-Control]: Error while SaveControl. Saving the added control failed!", e));
                    }
                }, null);
    }
}
```

}

```
public abstract class ServiceAgentBase<T> : ServiceBase, IServiceAgentBase<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ServiceAgentBase&lt;T&gt;"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    protected ServiceAgentBase() : base()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ServiceAgentBase&lt;T&gt;"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">service uri</param>
    protected ServiceAgentBase(Uri uri) : base(uri)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attaches an entity to the service context
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">entity to attach</param>
    public virtual void Attach(T entity)
    {
        this.Context.Detach(entity);

        ////persist changes regardless of whether the underlying entity has changed
        this.Context.AttachTo(entity.GetType().Name + "s", entity, "*");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes an entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">entity to delete</param>
    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        this.Context.DeleteObject(entity);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates an entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">entity to update</param>
    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        this.Context.UpdateObject(entity);
    }
}
```

The only remarkable thing in ServiceBase is that we create the context and use Json

```
 this.Context.Format.UseJson();
```

If I comment out this line and use Atompub instead, everything works fine...
Has anyone of you the same problem? Are there any solutions for that?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Traces from Fiddler

**JSON:**

```
POST http://localhost/MyService/MyDataService.svc/Controls HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata

{"odata.type":"Ria.DevelopmentModel.Control","Processes@odata.bind":
["http://localhost/MyService/MyDataService.svc/Processes(3)"],
"Employees@odata.bind":["http://localhost/MyService/MyDataService.svc/Employees(2627)"],
"Employees@odata.bind":["http://localhost/MyService/MyDataService.svc/Employees(2628)"],
"Accuracy":false,"Activity":null,"ActualStatus":0,"Automation":null,////All the other properties...}
```

**ATOM**

```
POST http://localhost/MyService/MyDataService.svc/Controls HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/atom+xml,application/xml
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<category term="Ria.DevelopmentModel.Control" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Processes" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Processes" href="http://localhost/MyService/MyDataService.svc/Processes(3)" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Employees" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Employees" href="http://localhost/MyService/MyDataService.svc/Employees(2627)" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Employees" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Employees" href="http://localhost/MyService/MyDataService.svc/Employees(2628)" />
<id /><title /><updated>2013-09-18T09:20:07Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml">
<m:properties><d:Accuracy m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:Accuracy><d:Activity m:null="true" /><d:ActualStatus m:type="Edm.Byte">0</d:ActualStatus><d:Automation m:type="Edm.Byte" m:null="true" /> ////All the other props....
```

Comment: Could you include the actual payload (or the relevant bit if the payload is huge) being sent over the wire in Atom and JSON? You can use a tool like Fiddler to get this information, and it would help a lot with debugging this issue.

Comment: Thanks for including the payloads. It looks like a bug when we're writing out odata.bind. I'll take a closer look into our code and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug in the WCF Data Services client library. Specifically, if you call `AddLink()` multiple times in the same request with the same value for `sourceProperty` ("Employees" in your example) and you're using Json, the client library will generate an incorrect payload.

It's pretty cumbersome, but as a workaround until a fix is available, you could try to make sure that every time `BeginSaveChanges()` is called, `AddLink()` has only been called once per property since the last call to `BeginSaveChanges()`. For example, if a user invokes `AddEnforcingEmployee()` several times before clicking the save control, you could internally keep track of that list of links instead of calling `AddLink()` on the context immediately. Then, when the user does click "save", you could call `AddLink()` followed by `BeginSaveChanes()` repeatedly for each `AddEnforcingEmployee()` call.

Alternatively, you could continue to use Atom instead of JSON.

Sorry I don't have a better answer for you at this point. I'll update this response when a fix is available. (And thank you for reporting this!)